# Why does this happen when the for in loop is used in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, javascript-objects, for-in-loop

So I am trying to implement an object as a set in javascript, where there are no duplicate elements or specific order of elements in the collection. Here is my implementation with the regular for loop:

```
var Set = function(elements) {
    for(i=0;i<elements.length;i++) {
        this[elements[i]] = true;
    }
};
```

And this works as intended:

```
   y = new Set([4, 5, 6, 3, 2])
=> { '2': true, '3': true, '4': true, '5': true, '6': true }
```

However, if I used the for in loop, something really strange happens:

```
var Set = function(elements) {
    for(var elem in elements) {
        this[elem] = true;
    }
};

   t = new Set([9, 8, 7])
=> { '0': true, '1': true, '2': true }
```

Why does the for in loop cause the elements 0, 1, and 2 to be in my set, and not the numbers I had in my array originally?

Comment: Looks like it is only counting the indexes and not the values within the indexes

Comment: Because `for in` iterates _keys_.

Comment: See this answer. The for loop is intended to enumerate properties, not arrays. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3010848

Comment: Oh, ok, I understand it now, this works differently than the for in loop in python..

Comment: I see people saying what you did wrong, but not how to fix it. "of" is the word you're looking for. `for (var elem of elements)` would give you the 9, 8, and 7.

Answer (score 3):

`for ... in` loops loop over the keys of the object specified in after `in`.  The keys of your array are 0, 1, 2 (arrays are objects with key value pairs).

Answer (score 2):

`for-in` loops do not loop through the *values* of elements, it loops through the *keys*.

An array does have keys, using indexes, so what you get for each `elem` is the index.

A resource for you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are using an array. Arrays are just objects whose keys are indices.

i.e.

```
[9, 8, 7] => {0: 9, 1: 8, 2: 7}
```

Once you understand this implementation, you'll see that it is actually doing the right thing.